# Using external .properties in Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, maven, thymeleaf, properties-file

**In summary**, I need to find a way to use value from .properties files in a Thymeleaf template.

**In details now**, I want to have Google Analytics on my page. There are development and production application build profiles. Each of these profiles has its directory with properties. The account details are in these properties files.

For now I assign the appropriate values to variables in the model and use them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    var _gaId = /*[[${googleAnalyticsId}]]*/'';//these are the variables I'm talking about
    var _gaDomainName = /*[[${googleAnalyticsDomainName}]]*/'';
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', _gaId]);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', _gaDomainName]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

But it seems quite dirty, let alone the manoeuvring that needs to be done in order to change any of these values.

What I'd like to do in the page template is to just point to the property name like we do in Spring with @Value. E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    var _gaId = /*[[${google.analytics.id}]]*/'';//I want to assign values directly from the properties file
    var _gaDomainName = /*[[${google.analytics.domain.name}]]*/'';
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', _gaId]);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', _gaDomainName]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `#` instead of the `$` while reading the property value? Like `#{google.analytics.id}`

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use the standard message-source way with `#{googleAnalyticsDomainName}`?

Comment: First of all, the pieces of information are not messages, so they can't go into the Messages bundle, if this what you are offering. And well, secondly, I wouldn't know how to specify another message source for the thymeleaf engine.

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine You can use addDefaultMessage of the StandardResolver simple look to the api, perhaps there are better ways.